# Meaning of a dream

Tags: krishna, dream

What does it mean to see the following things in dream?

> There is a temple of lord Krishna a priest is praying there, suddenly the priest turns into lord krishna many devotees come they also turn in to lord krishna.

Comment: 3 possible reasons, 1st Adwait which is very much true,2nd is that from Shrimad Bhagwatam which says when a devotee dies, he attains the form of 4 handed Vishnu. Thus he gets Sarupya with him. 3rd is that it's the hint that you must start looking in everyone Krishn himself, without any bheda buddhi. As said in Bhagwat geeta.

Comment: The question will be closed due to being opinion-based, but I will still give you my opinion so you can perhaps get some satisfaction. Atman & Brahman are one & the same. Some will realize before others. This is not simply something to know but to experience. The implications are vast. It must be processed for some time to fully comprehend. 